# plupload in a SPA with Angular and Breeze

Tags: javascript, angularjs, breeze, plupload

I have a SPA app that uses angular and breeze, allowing field personnel to create new entities and submit them to our ERP in realtime. They can take pictures and have them uploaded as well (currently using a mix of iPad, iPhone and Galaxy devices). This has all been working just fine.

Now we would like to resize the images before they're uploaded to save on bandwidth, speed up the app and make it easier to attach them to email messages down the line. I got plupload (2.1.2) to work as an angular directive and it resizes/uploads images perfectly. The problem is when a new entity is created and the page is "reloaded", plupload no longer responds. I use the following for the input field:

```
<input type="file"
capture="camera"
accept="image/*"
id="cameraInput"
pl-upload
pl-auto-upload="false"
pl-files-model="files"
pl-multi-params-model="multiParams"
pl-instance="uploadotron"
pl-entity="vm.report"
ng-file-select="vm.handleFile($files)"
ng-disabled="vm.state == 'Unchanged'" />
```

The options I'm using for plupload are:

```
var options = {runtimes: 'html5', 
       browse_button : 'cameraInput',
       multi_selection: false,
       container: 'uploadcontainer',
       max_file_size: '20mb',
       multiple_queues: false,
       url : '.breeze/Files/Upload',
       flash_swf_url : iAttrs.plFlashSwfUrl,
       silverlight_xap_url : iAttrs.plSilverlightXapUrl,
       filters: [{title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,jpeg,gif,png,tiff,pdf"}],
       resize: {
           width: 1024,
           height: 768,
           crop: false,
           quality: 90
    }
}
```

As a partial workaround I found that passing an instance object (pl-instance="uploadotron" above, where uploadotron is attached to $scope in the controller) to the directive allows me to manually add a file and trigger the upload, but this only fires ng-file-select on every second attempt on the iPad. The galaxy works correctly.

So the questions are:

1. Why would plupload stop working when a new entity has been added, and how to fix it? I put in a ton of console.log statements and verified that initialization of plupload appeared to be happening via the directive when the page reloads, but the browse event no longer fires. If I leave the page entirely and come back, it starts working again. That is not exactly user friendly though.
2. Why would the iPad (safari, iOS 7.1.1) only call the ng-file-select function on every second photo/file selection?

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Update:

I have solved my problem by using the FileAPI found on github (https://github.com/mailru/FileAPI/), and writing my own directive to call it. Works like a charm now. I think part of the issue was that ng-file-select is part of a different directive, and I didn't realize that right away. Meaning I was essentially mixing two directives in the same input element.